# Adding Client-Side Validation to Partial View with AjaxOptions.OnSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've been trying to enable client-side validation for a partial view and I've found myself stuck.  I've added the code to the AjaxOptions OnSuccess property, but nothing happens.  I should point out that I'm relatively new to jQuery and, to be honest, I'm trying to work my way through my first MVC application by learning as I go.  If anyone has a better way of doing this,please let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code for my view is as follows:

```
@model NorthwindLight.Models.Order

@using NorthwindLight.HtmlHelpers

@using NorthwindLight.Models

@{

    ViewBag.Title ="Create";

    AjaxOptions newOpts = new AjaxOptions();

    newOpts.UpdateTargetId ="tabledata";

    newOpts.InsertionMode =InsertionMode.InsertAfter;

    newOpts.OnSuccess ="function (tabledata) {$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(tabledata));};";

    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "mainform", id = "mainform" })) {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   <fieldset>

       <legend>Order</legend>

      ... Code for entering Order ommitted for brevity

       <legend>Order Details</legend>

   <br />

   <table>

       <thead>

           <tr>

               <th>Product</th>

               <th>Unit Price</th>

               <th>Quantity</th>

               <th></th>

           </tr>

       </thead>

       <tbody id="tabledata">

        @if (Model.OrderDetails == null)

        {

            @Html.Partial("OrderDetailPartial", new OrderDetail())

        }

       else

       {

           foreach (var orderDetail in Model.OrderDetails)

           {

                 @Html.Partial("OrderDetailPartial", orderDetail)

           }

       }

       </tbody>

   </table>

    @Ajax.ActionLink("New Record", "OrderDetailPartial", newOpts)

    </fieldset>

    }

    <div>

       <a href="javascript:document.mainform.submit();">Create</a> | 

        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")

    </div>
```

Here are the script tags that are included in _Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DeleteRow.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui.datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've seen lots of examples on the net that seem similar to this, but I've not been able to get any of them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this with help from another forum. The first step is to create a new FormContext in the partial view, if one does not already exist.

```
if(ViewContext.FormContext == null)
{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
```

You then add this jQuery script below to your scripts folder.  I called mine PartialViewValidation.js

```
function Success(formName) {
    $(formName).removeData("validator");
    $(formName).removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formName);
}
```

I then added a script tag to _Layout.cshtml.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/PartialViewValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally, I added a call to the jQuery function to the onSuccess property of the AjaxOptions object, which I called newOpts. The main form that the HTML is injected into is called #mainform

```
newOpts.OnSuccess = "Success('#mainform')";
```

Client-side validation now takes place for the HTML elements that are dynamically added to the View from the Ajax call.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.  I did add the code before the `@model` declaration as mentioned by @ElieSaber in the other answer. (Didn't test it with this below)

Answer (score 1):

MickySmig's answer is correct just be sure to put The FormContext Code Before the @model tag which mean before your model type in the partial view.

Comment: @osyan not sure that Elie needed to do that given that all other relevant code (besides `@model`) is provided in the answer that they reference.